# Aggregate / average 10 fields from 300 nodes and display on a page

Tags: 7, views

I have about 250 nodes of data (which will probably grow to 300) which I want to aggregate so that the user can see the average value for each of the fields. Each node would contain about 40 fields but I would only need to show about averaged values of 10 of these at any one time. The final view (or page) I wish to produce would therefore show 10 fields in which the data was the average of the fields in the 250-300 nodes. There would be 4 similar pages, each drawing a new set of 10 fields from that 250 nodes to average.

I would like to know what a workable solution producing this might be. It is not going to be a high traffic site, and would probably only receive a handful of views per week. Therefore optimizing the efficiency of this operation is not as crucial as it might be. However a solution that was efficient and simple would be preferable :)

I considered drawing all 250-300 nodes into a view and using the [views calc](https://drupal.org/node/359981) module to create the averages of each field. I would hide the original data and only show the 10 pieces of averaged data. From looking at views calc this seems like it should work, but it also seems inefficient. Can anyone give an opinion on whether this approach would work or suggest better solutions?

Comment: I think writing your own module (and running the queries directly) would be the fastest solution.

Comment: Thanks t1gor could you elaborate on how you would go about doing this, as it would be new for me? Would this mean hardcoding the required SQL queries into the module?

Comment: Ok, so I'm starting to get my head around how i might be able to do this in a custom module using the [Database API](https://drupal.org/developing/api/database). Toronto Website Developer has a helpful [video tutorial on database interactions by a custom module](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3h9L3c1g454&list=PLZaG0MNecryN99benfhaU0zfZHcA4upRm&index=7)